# targeting amd64 is not compatible with the project's target platform x86 c#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a .NET application (C#) using VS 2013 in 64-bits plat-form.
 When I deploy it I got this message.

> targeting amd64 is not compatible with the project's target platform x86 setup project

Building not success

The problem comes from CrystalReport I think. Maybe I'll need a dll file target X86. What shall I need to do ?

Comment: It is a *build warning*, not a deployment error.  You just get a warning that the compiler saw you using a 32-bit reference assembly and your program is compiled to target AnyCPU.  In other words, good odds that it is going to crash with a BadImageFormatException on a 64-bit operating system.  About 100% odds with CrystalReports when you don't deploy its 64-bit version.  Just set the Platform target to x86 and you won't have that problem.

Comment: Actually when I want to build the setup I face a red cross Target AMD 64 not compt whith targer X86

Answer (score 4):

Had a frustrating hour getting the same error message when Visual Studio was trying to build an installer, but it was targeting a different dll.

The solution was to just close and open Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Visual Studio 2010. The project had no notable changes in a while, but suddenly this error started showing.
 Closing Visual Studio, deleting every 'bin' and every 'obj' folder in the project, opening Visual Studio, then rebuilding solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio. On the menu bar, choose Build, Configuration Manager. Here you can configure your project for the target environment.

You will need to configure the project itself to have the same target environment (amd64) as the build and the libraries you're using.

Comment: The project target is by default X86 and the application will work on 32 bits Operating system so I needn't to change the target to X64. 
I'm trying to fix the problem and guarding the target X86 If I change it it 64 it won't work on 32Bits OS.

Comment: The server that is running the application and crystal reports is 64bit correct?

Comment: Yes sure. But It'll [The application] work on 32bits OS

Comment: Are the crystal report libraries 32bit? If they are not I'm not sure why you want it to run in 32bit.

Comment: Because the OS in which i'm going to install the application is 32-bits. Do u have another alternative to fix that error.

Comment: It sounds like the crystal dlls are 64bit and you will need to change the target platform or find the x86 version of the dlls.

Comment: Should be able to contact the vendor for those.